# Sort a list of tuples in Python where the tuples are list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

There is almost a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775228/python-sort-list-of-tuple) , but my question is slightly different. Lets say I have the flowing list:

```
my_list = [('a', [0.2, 0.28, 0.3]), ('b', [-0.09, 0.37, 0.4])]
```

I am trying to sort this list based on the second elements of the tuples i.e., 0.28 and 0.37 descending. This is what I have so far, which is not right.

```
import operator
my_list.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
print(my_list)
[('a', [0.2, 0.28, 0.3]), ('b', [-0.09, 0.37, 0.4])]
```

I can think of a not efficient way, but I am dealing with a large dataset and trying to be as efficient as possible. Thanks

Comment: You aren't sorting by the second element of the tuple. You are sorting by the second element of the second element of the tuple. Just use `my_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[1][1])`

Comment: Are you trying to sort the whole list or the tuples in each sublist? You can't sort tuples themselves, those are immutable.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
```

---

**Why do you get your output?**

`operator.itemgetter(1)` is just the second element of each tuple which is a list, not the second element of this list. *You are passing wrong `key` to `sort` function.*

You have to index twice as is in the code above. First index to get the list inside tuple, then index the list to get the second element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

For example, the list `[0.2, 0.28, 0.3]` is element 1 of the tuple `('a', [0.2, 0.28, 0.3])` at the top level of what you're sorting. The `0.28` that you want to sort based on is element 1 of *that*; so you want to sort based on indexing into the data like `[1][1]`. `operator.itemgetter` won't do multiple indexing steps like that, but you can define it manually:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda element:element[1][1], reverse=True)
```